# How to install mips64-elf-binutils/gcc?

Tags: gcc

How do I install `mips64-elf-binutils` and `mips64-elf-gcc`?

`sudo apt-get install mips64-elf-binutils` doesn't work.

I'm on Linux Mint Cinnamon 64-bit.

Comment: Did you search that package is provided?

sudo apt-get update 
apt-cache search mips64-elf-binutils

Comment: @yw_in_k `E: The update command takes no arguments` It said it didn't exist when installing though, and I'm wondering what the correct name is.

Comment: You may search by keywords like mips64, mips64-elf. 
None of them exist, you need to compile source codes.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Better yet, you can just download the prebuilt code here
https://github.com/tj90241/n64chain/releases
To use it you will want to point your makefile to use the tools directory instead of trying to install it into your usr directory since gcc in configured in this case to expect the tools directory to be in a specific layout.

I know this is old but I was getting the same problem and think I found the solution
You need to download the n64chain and build it yourself
This link has the source and instructions on how you can build it yourself
https://github.com/tj90241/n64chain

> To build the toolchain, first put your boot code named header.bin on
>   the libn64 folder. Run build-posix64-toolchain.sh in the tools folder
>   on a bash-compatible shell to start building the cross-compiler.
>   Prerequisites are GMP, MPFR and MPC with development headers,
>   build-essential, and bison, which can be installed via apt install
>   build-essential libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev libgmp-dev flex bison on
>   Ubuntu. On Mac, the Xcode command-line tools are also required. The
>   other prerequisites can be installed via the homebrew package manager
>   like so brew install mpfr isl libmpc gmp flex bison && brew link bison
>   --force.
>
> There is also a Windows compatible version build-win64-toolchain.sh
>   that still requires a UNIX-like environment to run.
>
> After the custom GCC build is completed, you should be able to build
>   the helloworld example by running make inside helloworld folder or
>   with make -C helloworld on project root. This will also build the
>   libn64 dependency on the project root. When it is complete you should
>   have a .z64 rom image ready to be run on a Nintendo 64. The same
>   procedure applies for the rdpdemo and threadtest examples.